# Flutter switch animation is not showing in Alert Dialog

Tags: flutter, boolean

I have an alert dialog with a switch. If I press the switch, the boolean changes like I want it to (I have it set so the homepage background color changes based on the bool), but the switch animation does not register until I close out of the alert dialog and re-open it again. I tried wrapping it in a StatefulBuilder like I saw in another post, but in that case, the animation works but the bool does not change. I am trying to share this bool value throughout my app, so I'm using Shared Preferences.

here is the full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool bulb = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bulb ? Colors.white : Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                          content: Column(children: [
                        Switch(
                          value: bulb,
                          onChanged: (bool isChecked) async {
                            final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                            setState(() {
                              bulb = isChecked;
                              prefs.setBool('bulb', isChecked);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        StatefulBuilder(builder:
                            (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                          return Column(children: [
                            Switch(
                              value: bulb,
                              onChanged: (bool isChecked) async {
                                final prefs =
                                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                setState(() {
                                  bulb = isChecked;
                                  prefs.setBool('bulb', isChecked);
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ]);
                        })
                      ])));
            })
      ]),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool bulb = false;
  Future openDialog() => showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) => AlertDialog(
                  content: Column(children: [
                Switch(
                  value: bulb,
                  onChanged: (bool isChecked) async {
                    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    setState(() {
                      bulb = isChecked;
                      prefs.setBool('bulb', isChecked);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    child: Text("Save")),
              ]))));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bulb ? Colors.white : Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () async {
              await openDialog();
              setState(() {});
            }),
      ]),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, but it can technically be many things: try to change the `setState` name in the statefulbuider to something else and use that setstate. also, play with the `context`,

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the full code?

Comment: ok, I've added the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `StatefulBuilder` itself.

Now, when you are calling `setState` inside the dialog, only the state inside the dialog is changing. The state of the screen remains the same. This is why switch changed animation is happening but the `bulb` value in the screen is not changing.

The workaround is, you can use a callback function to call `setState` in the screen too, when the value of switch changes.